# Problem with "Personal_Sign" in ethereum.request - "Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address."

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, digital-signature, metamask

I am getting a problem when I run this statement in the console window (from browser) to get signature of the account:

> ethereum.request({ method: "personal_sign", params: [account, hash] });

I did not used to have this problem, it works fine and returns a promise with the digital signature of the account (from Metamask). It would open up Metamask, I would do a digital signing and return the result of the digital signature to the promise.

Now it reports an error whenever I run the statement. The error message is:

code: -32602
message: "Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address."

Has something changed? I could not find any other details from ethereum.org or Metamask. If anyone has some knowledge on this, what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [personal_sign docs](https://metamask.github.io/api-playground/api-documentation/#personal_sign), you need to pass two parameters

- A hex-encoded UTF-8 string to present to the user. (not hash any string)
- The address of the requested signing account.

  ```
  const signedData = await ethereum?.request({
      method: "personal_sign",
      params: [
        JSON.stringify(messageToSign),
        //await ethereum?.request({method: "eth_requestAccounts"})[0]
        account,
      ],
    });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First element of params ("account") have to be one of the connected accounts.

You can access accounts with;

```
window.ethereum
  .request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
  .then(accounts => {
    console.log(accounts);
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was able to find the solution to my original question without having to use the eth_requestAccounts method. I will share it, I realized that this is not known to many devs because it is a Web3 and blockchain issue more than that of the typical full-stack development.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with MetaMask and the Ethereum window object in the browser.

Originally I tested the contract on a testnet using an injected Web3 provider.

When I was trying to test locally I used one of the JVM generated accounts.

You should not use them. Instead use a MetaMask account (copy the address) and do the ff:

assign the address to a variable (do the same with the hash):

account = Metamask address,
hash = bytes32 value of your hashed message

I can then issue the **ethereum.request** command that will run the "personal_sign" method with the parameters of account and hash.

The promise will return the digital signature of the account when signing a message.